# Using Modal from 2 pages - error - Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I created a modal and named it `worksmodal`.

It opens from page `showworks`. Everything works fine.

**New requirement** - I had to open the same modal from `Notificatons` page as well, so I called it from there too.

**Problem:** Now it is opening from `Notifications page`, when I try to open from `showworks page`, it gives error-

> `WorksmodalPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: NotificationsPageModule and ShowworksPageModule! Please consider moving WorksmodalPage to a higher module that imports NotificationsPageModule and ShowworksPageModule.`

**Few things for you to note**-

1. When app opens, by Default `Dashboard page` opens and it calls **Notification popover page**,which in turn calls `worksmodal page`
2. `showworks page` is opened from menu which also calls `worksmodal page`. Error comes here
3. Disabled decalaration from `worksmodal.module.ts`

`//  declarations: [WorksmodalPage]`

Now if I remove `WorksmodalPage` from Declaration of `showworks.module.ts`, it gives error-

`WorksmodalPage is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

What do I need to do so it works from both pages ?

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of the modal component into its own module, and make sure to export it in that module. Then import that module into the pages you are using it in.

Comment: More details can be found here. https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules